# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 with UEFI/secure boot enabled. Dualboot with win 8.1

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

First of all: I am well aware of the following the [existing thread on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), as well as [the guide by Rod Smith](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html), and I have read on the problem on various forums for maybe 10 hours (2 days), but could not find an answer to my question.

I want to install Ubuntu but I do NOT want to disable secure boot at any time during the installation process. Is this possible?
I have an Acer Aspire V5-573G and Windows8.1 installed.

So far all my tries of even just launching a Live-Install from USB end in a black screen after choosing at the "Live- or full install to hdd" screen.

Not sure if I am allowed to ask this, but would it help to take any other Linux Distribution (Fedora)?

I never had a Linux installation running, so any solutions that need massive Linux knowlegde might not help me. I would still like to hear about them thou. :D Thx in advance.

---

Also, I am well aware of the bad reputation of secure boot, but please just accept my wish to keep it activated ALL the time. (Lets say my employer forces me to...)

Comment: I wish to do the same thing with a HP envy desktop and get a black screen with just one under score on it. I also cannot find a soulution. I will submit a bug report. I went thru windows 8 boot cd/dvd sequence and have a ubuntu 13.10 dvd. also turned off fast boot. system inits because i see HP bios splash screen then the blank screen with just one underscore. trying to understand this link, my help us https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem by disabling fast boot in HP bios.

The [following link](http://www.zdnet.com/more-fun-with-windows-8-uefi-secure-boot-fedora-and-ubuntu-7000009292/) confirmed it could be done.

After reading this article I went into HP bios (esc or F10) Security, Secure boot and Disabled Fast Boot.

My ubuntu 13.10 and fedora 20 live dvds would boot and install in efi / secure boot mode and reboot windows, ubuntu and fedora if I went into firmware boot (F9)

(actually worked booting to ubuntu grub then windows or ubuntu, but after installing fedora it would boot to fedora only unless I used F9 boot menu. Trying to learn efibootmgr to fix this problem)

Most of the tutorials mention disabling fast boot in windows under power options, but in my case I had to also disable it in the bios.